# Converting solutions back to equations (inverse of ToRules)

Tags: equation-solving, rule

If I solve an equation (or a system of equations), I get output like

```
{{a -> 5, b -> 4}, {a -> 2, b -> 3}}
```

I would like to convert this a statment, like

```
(a == 5 && b == 4) || (a == 2 && b == 3)
```

Currently, I'm doing this with the somewhat janky piece of code

```
solution // Apply[Equal, #, {2}] & // MapApply[And] // Apply[Or]
```

But this feels very unstable.  Is there a simpler or more stable way to perform this conversion?

Comment: What about `... /. Rule->Equal` ?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann that's a great way to deal with the first step, very self-explanatory.

Comment: How is it unstable?

Comment: I'm blindly replacing the head of all terms at a given level, it'd be very easy for something to go wrong.  For instance, if I performed these operations in the reverse order:
`solution // Apply[Or]  // MapApply[And] // Apply[Equal, #, {2}] &`
this works, but only if there's at least two solutions and at least two rules in each solution, otherwise it doesn't error out but produces completely incorrect output.  I'm trying to rewrite it in a way where I can be more sure it isn't doing something wrong.

Comment: So the form to be transformed is always a list of a list of rules, never just a list of rules? All other forms should remain unaltered?

Comment: Yep, because that's the form that the output of `Solve` takes - it doesn't really matter what it does when fed something that's not the output of `Solve`

Comment: OK, I included an alternative that can handle the forms of output of both `FindRoot` and `Solve`, but most of the alternatives in my answer are for the `Solve` form.

Comment: Sorry, another question just occurred to me: If it's to handle the output of `Solve`, should it transform `{{}}` and `{}`? They're easy to add. I just didn't think of it until now.

Comment: `{}` ought to transform to `False` (which I think it does under the original), there isn't really anything sensible to do with full dimensional solutions that I can think of.

Answer (score 4):

First you may change the rules into equations: `HoldPattern[ x1_ -> x2_] -> x1 == x2`

Then you may transform the nested lists into Or and And: `{{x1__}, {x2__}} :> Or[ And[x1], And[x2]]`

```
{{a -> 5, b -> 4}, {a -> 2, b -> 3}} /. 
  HoldPattern[ x1_ -> x2_] -> x1 == x2  /. {{x1__}, {x2__}} :> Or[ And[x1], And[x2]]

(* (a == 5 && b == 4) || (a == 2 && b == 3) *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a modification of the OP's approach that will transform an expression only if it is a list of list of rules:

```
{{a -> 5, b -> 4}, {a -> 2, b -> 3}} //
 Replace[{r : {__Rule} ..} :> (And @@ Equal @@@ # &) /@ Or[r]]

(*  (a == 5 && b == 4) || (a == 2 && b == 3)  *)
```

If we use `ReplaceAll` instead of `Replace`, then it would potentially transform a subexpression that matched the pattern.

To get something that would transform an expression consisting of a single solution `{a -> 5, b -> 4}` or a list of solutions, then the following modification would work:

```
{a -> 5, b -> 4} //
 Replace[
  s_List :> (Replace[s,
      r : {__Rule} :> And @@ Equal @@@ r, {0, 1}] //
     Replace[{sys__And} :> Or[sys]])
  ]

(*  a == 5 && b == 4  *)

{{a -> 5, b -> 4}, {a -> 2, b -> 3}} //
 Replace[
  s_List :> (Replace[s,
      r : {__Rule} :> And @@ Equal @@@ r, {0, 1}] //
     Replace[{sys__And} :> Or[sys]])
  ]

(*  (a == 5 && b == 4) || (a == 2 && b == 3)  *)
```

Again, we use `Replace` instead of `ReplaceAll` to make sure the expression has the correct form of a solution.

Here's another way:

```
{{a -> 5, b -> 4}, {a -> 2, b -> 3}} // Replace[
  sol : {{__Rule} ..} :> 
   Apply[Or, Apply[And, Apply[Equal, sol, {2}], {1}], {0}]
  ]

(*  (a == 5 && b == 4) || (a == 2 && b == 3)  *)
```

The nested `Apply` is really a `Fold` operation, but the explicit nesting is shorter than the following `Fold`:

```
{{a -> 5, b -> 4}, {a -> 2, b -> 3}} // Replace[
  sol : {{__Rule} ..} :> Fold[
    Function[{s, f}, Apply[First@f, s, {Last@f}]],
    sol,
    Transpose[{{Equal, And, Or}, Range[2, 0, -1]}]]
  ]

(*  (a == 5 && b == 4) || (a == 2 && b == 3)  *)
```

Any of the `Replace` methods can be packaged as a function instead of an anonymous operator. For example:

```
toEquations[sol : {{__Rule} ..}] := 
  Apply[Or, Apply[And, Apply[Equal, sol, {2}], {1}], {0}];
```

Comment: To handle the `{{}}` and `{}` outputs from `Solve[]`, add a rule for each: `expr // Replace[{ {{}} -> True, {} -> False, {r : {__Rule} ..} :>... }]` and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

As a one-liner

```
Map[# /. Rule -> Equal /. List -> And &, expr] /. List -> Or
(*(a == 5 && b == 4) || (a == 2 && b == 3)*)
```